# why am i getting negative values for my timeinterval?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimer, countdown

I have no idea what is happening. I am trying to make a timer that works by comparing dates. When I start the timer, sometimes it works and then randomly stops, and sometimes it just returns the value of the timeInterval. It seems to only work correctly when the time interval is negative. This is my method:

```
-(IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender{
    if (timer == nil) {
        [startButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:testTask.timeInterval]; //instance variable
    } else {
        [startButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

}
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval updatedTimeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
    if (updatedTimeInterval > 0){
        if (self.timer)
        {
            [self timerExpired];
            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.timer = nil;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        testTask.timeInterval = updatedTimeInterval;
        NSLog(@"%.2f", testTask.timeInterval);
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)round(testTask.timeInterval);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
                        seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
    timerLabel.text = string;
    NSLog(@"%f", testTask.timeInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're subtracting the later date, `currentDate`, from the earlier `date`. I told you to do it the other way around: `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date]`

Comment: Just changed it to that. Now when I press Start, the timer immediately  displays 1193046 hours...

Comment: If `date` is the variable you're using to store the start time of the timer, it should be set with the current date -- `date = [NSDate date];`, not with `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:`

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason `timeIntervalSinceNow` is not called `timeIntervalUntilNow`...

Also known as: the time elapsed **since now** is negative if the date in question is earlier than the current date/time. It would be positive if the date was later in time than the current date. (Just a bit of logic and/or English semantics :))

```
   Earlier date      Current date
        ^                  ^
        +------------------+
              since now: (earlier date) - (current date)... that's < 0
```

Comment: Just changed it to that. Now when I press Start, the timer immediately displays 1193046 hours

Comment: @EvilAegis Changed... what to what?

Comment: NSTimeInterval updatedTimeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate] to  NSTimeInterval updatedTimeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date]. I switched the dates basically

Comment: @EvilAegis Ah OK. In this case, I suggest you leave out the `NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:]` etc. part. Simply store the interval as an `NSTimeInterval` instance variable, and use it when calculating the remaining time.

Comment: What do you mean by use it to calculate the remaining time? How is that different from just decrementing a time interval :O?

Comment: @EvilAegis `int hours = interval / 3600; int minutes = (interval - hours * 3600) / 60; int secs = (interval - hours * 3600) % 60;`

Comment: lol i dont want to do that because i need to make it accurate. i was reccomended what i am currently doing with the dateSinceNow because it gives you an accurate time interval :/